# Need help understanding the existence of a projection map $pr_2:M \wedge X_+ \rightarrow X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cobordism

I am reading [these](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Ehrm/papers/cobordism.pdf) introductory notes to cobordism theory, however cobordism theory is not required to understand my question. I just need help understanding a certain map.

On page number 8 the author claims that there is a map $pr_1:MO(k) \wedge X_+ \rightarrow MO(k)$ where $MO(k)$ is just some based topological space and $X_+$ is $X \sqcup *$. I understand the existance of this map.

However, they also claim on the top of page 9 that there exists a map $pr_2:MO(k) \wedge X_+ \rightarrow X$, this confuses me since $MO(k) \wedge X_+ = (MO(k) \times X)/(\{ * \} \times X)$ thus $pr_2$ should correspond to a map $pr_2:MO(k) \times X \rightarrow X$ which maps the subspace $\{*\} \times X$ to a single point in $X$ and the obvious choice of $pr_2$, namely $(m,x) \mapsto x$, obviously does not.

This doesn't make sense to me. Am I just missing something? It seems unlikely that $pr_2$ is a typo on behalf of the author since it makes perfect sense to wish for such a map to exist given the context.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: He is not claiming such a map exists. He is only saying that $M$ included into the sphere and composed with the embedding of the sphere into the Thom space, misses any points that cause the projection map to be not well defined, and so we can map it into $X$ by reading off the coordinates.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you. Post this comment as an answer and I will accept it to close the question. @ConnorMalin